# Looping Ul and Li through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to loop through Ul and li in jquery and need to get the label value in jquery.I am doing an asp.net c#

My Html is as below

```html
<ul id="ctl00_DashboardContent_cblUsers" class="reprp checkWrp scroll" style="width: 100%;">
  <li>
    <span title="Thomas"><input name="ctl00$DashboardContent$cblUsers$1" />
 <label for="ctl00_DashboardContent_cblUsers_0">Thomas</label>
  </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span title="Abraham"><input name="ctl00$DashboardContent$cblUsers$1" />
        <label for="ctl00_DashboardContent_cblUsers_1">Abraham</label>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the label value through jquery

I have tried the following code, but it is not looping

```
$('<%=cblUsers.ClientID %>').find('li').each(function (index, element) {
});
```

Comment: Is this php $('<%=cblUsers.ClientID %>') ?

Comment: `$('#ctl00_DashboardContent_cblUsers li label')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<%=cblUsers.ClientID %>'
```

appears to be unprocessed server-side.  You want to use a CSS selector such as:

```
$('#ctl00_DashboardContent_cblUsers')
```

Comment: The `ctl00_DashboardContent_cblUsers` is a server side generated client Id, if you add certain elements to this page in the future, that client id could change and then the jQuery example above would not work anymore. Getting the client Id via `<%=cblUsers.ClientID %>` would always work because the client Id would be generated from the server each time the mark up is rendered and sent to the browser. The only problem the OP had was that they did not have the `#` in front of there generated client Id.

Comment: If the javascript code was in a separate stand alone  file, not in the file with the server code, I would suggest passing in the generated client Id to the stand alone file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the proper query selector for getting an element by Id. Try this:

Notice the `#`

```
 $('#' + '<%=cblUsers.ClientID %>').find('li').each(function (index, element) { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.reprp').find('li').each(function (index, element) {
        var text = $(this).find('label').text();
        console.log( text );
    });
</script>
```